# How to read mail body

Tags: php, email

I want to read every thing mail body it may be html in body, text or image as well

For that I am using this script

```
$msgStream = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX','abc@gmail.com','abc');
$emails = imap_search($msgStream,'UNSEEN');
if(!empty($emails) > 0){
    foreach($emails as $mailNumber){
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($msgStream,$mailNumber,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($msgStream,$mailNumber, 1.1);
        imap_clearflag_full($msgStream, $mailNumber, "\\Seen");
    }
}else{
    echo "<h2>No new mail found</h2>";
}
```

But it only return me plain text from body.

There are no images and html.
How can I read them ?

Comment: A mail body can contain multiple parts so you need to iterate through them, checking each part to see what they contain and fetch the part accordingly. Which part you fetch is the third parameter in in `imap_fetchbody()`-function. Use [`imap_fetchstructure()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) to the get mail structure. Also, read the comments in the manual for that function and you'll get some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson third parameter seems to be required, what should i pass as third parameter so that it will return all the sections available instead of particular section only. So i can decide which data i need to store.

Comment: Yes, the third arg is required, since that's what's telling the function what part to fetch. Did you follow my suggestion about reading about `imap_fetchstructure()` in the PHP manual? As I mentioned, you need to use that function to get the structure of the body + that manual page has an example for how you can extract what you need. (Check the user comments).